# Intel SSD terminology

Tags: ssd, specifications

What is the difference in an Intel SSD spec, between "end to end data protection" and "enhanced power loss protection"?

(And what exactly do these terms mean in their specs?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### End to end data protection:

> Handling soft errors requires many design steps.  A good first step is to protect the SRAMs and DRAM with parity or EDAC.  But those don’t protect flip flops in the controller’s logic circuitry, and soft errors there can also corrupt user data.  **One approach that Intel takes is to envelop the user data in what’s known as end-to-end data protection**.  When the host writes a sector, the controller appends a set of Cyclic Redundancy Check (CRC) bits (think of parity on steroids) before passing the whole bundle through the rest of the circuitry to the NAND.  When the host later reads that sector, the controller checks that the CRC bits still jive with the user data.  If there’s been a bit flip, the CRC will detect it.  This is another aspect that can be worked out mathematically and shown to meet ultra-low silent error rate requirements.

[Data Integrity in Solid State Drives: What Supernovas Mean to You](https://itpeernetwork.intel.com/data-integrity-in-solid-state-drives-what-supernovas-mean-to-you/)

So it's a protection against small run time errors.

### Enhance power loss data protection:

> During an unsafe shutdown, firmware routines in the
>   Intel SSD 320 Series respond to power loss interrupt
>   and make sure both user data and system data in the
>   temporary buffers are transferred to the NAND media.
>   Additionally, given the energy provided by the
>   capacitor elements and urgency to recover data,
>   firmware de-prioritizes non essential controller
>   activities to quickly get into data saving mode ―
>   all with no impact on overall system performance.

[Enhanced power-loss data protection in
the Intel® Solid-State Drive 320 Series](https://newsroom.intel.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/11/2016/01/Intel_SSD_320_Series_Enhance_Power_Loss_Technology_Brief.pdf)

This is protection of data during power loss.

Comment: Thanks - perfect. I was surprised because CRC or other checks for data at rest or in the controller are standard on almost all storage media - HDDs, SSDs, etc. So I couldn't work out what it represented, and therefore, if the other one was actually *not* doing what i might have expected. Hence worry. Its now clear.